# Reading from text field database doesn't work

Tags: java, database

I created a text field that serves as a data base for Usernames and Passwords.

I tried to make a method that recognizes when there's already an existing username/password which are the same, but it doesn't seem to work.

I think that the problem is in the `while` loop condition (in `exists()`), but I can't find out how to fix it.

```
public class Login{
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner read;
    private static Formatter x;
    public static void main (String args[]){


        try{
            x = new Formatter("DataBase.txt");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try{
            read = new Scanner (new File("DataBase.txt"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        do{
            System.out.println("Type LOGIN to login, Type REGISTER to register");
            if (s.next().equals("REGISTER")){
                System.out.println("Insert username");
                String userName = s.next();
                while (exists(userName) == true){
                    System.out.println("ERROR! username already exists");
                    System.out.println("please selcet a different username");
                    userName = s.next();
                }System.out.println("username is legal");
                System.out.println("Insert password");
                String passWord =  s.next();
                while (exists(passWord)){
                    System.out.println("ERROR! password already exists");
                    System.out.println("please selcet a different password");
                    passWord = s.next();
                }
                x.format("%s %s"+System.lineSeparator(), userName,passWord);
                System.out.println("User created");
                System.out.println("Type continue to continue, or stop to close");
            }
        }while (s.next().equals("continue"));

        x.close();

    }

    public static Boolean exists(String str){
        while(read.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(read.next() +"," + str);
            if (read.next().equals(str)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the output you are getting that shows that it isn't working? (vs. what you are expecting?)

Comment: You call `read.next()` twice in a loop - what do you think this does? Also, always format your code using your IDE's auto format option before posting here - this code is illegible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First you have to remove the extra call to `next()` in `Syste.out..println` statement.

2) After adding data to `Formatter` you have to call `flush()`so that data gets written into `DataBase.txt` file.

3) Your instance variable `read` is opening the `DataBase.txt` file at the beginning itself when there is no data in the file. So your `exists` method will always returns `false`.

4) The [Formatter.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method is not used properly.

Here is the code which works:

```
public class Login {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Scanner read;
    private static Formatter x;

    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        try {
            x = new Formatter("DataBase.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        do {
            System.out.println("Type LOGIN to login, Type REGISTER to register");
            if (s.next().equals("REGISTER")) {
                System.out.println("Insert username");
                String userName = s.next();
                while (exists(userName) == true) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR! username already exists");
                    System.out.println("please selcet a different username");
                    userName = s.next();
                }
                System.out.println("username is legal");
                System.out.println("Insert password");
                String passWord = s.next();
                while (exists(passWord)) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR! password already exists");
                    System.out.println("please selcet a different password");
                    passWord = s.next();
                }
                x.format("%s%s%s%s", userName,
                        System.getProperty("line.separator"), passWord,
                        System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                System.out.println("User created");
                System.out
                        .println("Type continue to continue, or stop to close");
                x.flush();
            }
        } while (s.next().equals("continue"));

        x.close();

    }

    public static Boolean exists(String str) {
        try {
            read = new Scanner(new File("DataBase.txt"));
            while (read.hasNext()) {
                String data = read.next();
                System.out.println(data);
                if (data.equals(str)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            read.close();
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

as mentioned by Ambrish you can use cache to improve performance instead of reading data from the file every time.

Comment: Thanks, it works. First time i've heard of the flush method, the tutorial that i learnt from didn't mention it..

Answer (score 0):

You are reading 2 lines inside your `exists()` function. So there is 50% chance that you will get -ver result.

Here is the updated code:

```
public static Boolean exists(String str){
    while(read.hasNext()) {
        String line = read.next();
        System.out.println(line + "," + str);
        if (line.equals(str)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Above solution will in inefficient and you have to read file multiple time. Instead you can create a `cache` and reuse it.

Like:

```
static Map<String, String> entires; // Create Cache

public static Boolean existsUser(String str) {
    if (entires == null) {
        entires = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (read.hasNext()) {
            String[] line = read.next().trim().split(" ");
            entires.put(line[0], line[1]);
        }
    }

    return entires.containsKey(str);
}

public static Boolean existsPassword(String str, String user) {
    if (entires == null) {
        entires = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while (read.hasNext()) {
            String[] line = read.next().trim().split(" ");
            entires.put(line[0], line[1]);
        }
    }

    if (entires.containsKey(user)) {
        return entires.get(user).equals(str);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, you need to keep on updating your `cache` based on new entry and also you need to refactor your code to use these methods.

Comment: Thank you! Haven't got to using Caches yet, but i'll give it a try.